# Showing a isomorphism exists between a quotient group and another group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> We have $G_1 = GL(2,\mathbb{R}) \times GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ and 
>   $G_2 = \{(C,D) \in G_1 \mid \det(C) = \det(D)\}$. We want to show that 
>   $G_1/G_2 \cong {(\mathbb{R^*},\times})$.

So my approach for this is that we know
$G_1/G_2 = \{(A,B)G_2:(A,B) \in G_1\}$ and construct the map $f:G_1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R^*}$ given by $f(A,B) = \det(AB)$. But I am having trouble showing that this map is isomorphic, particularly showing that its one - one.